# Scroll without Touch in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scroll

I want to give animation in GridView. So that when the list gets prepared, it will scroll to given position without touching the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the methods `smoothScrollToPosition` and `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` to make the GridView go to that position.